# What is the difference between ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration and ServiceFabricClusterManifest?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My question regards updating the configuration for a Service Fabric standalone Windows cluster.

What is the difference between `ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration` and `ServiceFabricClusterManifest`?

Suppose that I want to change the `ApplicationPorts` setting, I see these options:

### Using ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration

1. use `Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration`
2. edit the **JSON** file
3. Start an upgrade using `Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade`

or

### Using ServiceFabricClusterManifest

1. Use `Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest`
2. edit the **XML** file
3. Start an upgrade using

   1. `Register-ServiceFabricClusterPackage -Config -ClusterManifestPath "ClusterConfigv2.xml"`
   2. `Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade -ClusterManifestVersion 2 -Config`

I tried to change `ApplicationPorts` via the ServiceFabricClusterManifest. We are now in a situation that the `ApplicationPorts` is different in the json (Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration) than the value in the XML (Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest)

My questions are:

- What is the difference between the two approaches?
- What is the approach I should take?
- Since the different `Get-` commands give different results, which is the way to see the actual applied configuration?

*update:*

I get the following error when I run the `Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade` command.

```
Exception             : System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
                           at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricClusterManagementClient7.EndUpgradeConfiguration(IFabricAsyncOperationC
                        ontext context)
                           at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WrapNativeAsyncInvoke>b__9(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context
                        )
                           at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedComplet
                        edSynchronously)
TargetObject          : Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterConnection
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Start-ServiceFa...gurationUpgrade], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartClusterConfigurationUpgradeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartClusterConfigurationUpgrade
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Answer (score 1):

For on premises deployments `Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade` is the supported mechanism and is the only one you should use. As long as you use only one mechanism you shouldn't receive inconsistent results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the supported approach. Unfortunately I get an exception when I try `Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade`. I have updated my question with the error details.

Comment: Is this in a clean cluster or the one where things have already diverged?

Comment: This is the cluster where things have already diverged. We used `Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade` on it for various updates.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed error is in the trace logs. Could u provide the 2 JSON files? Also, a common error is to upgrade without updating the json config version, which is the "clusterConfigurationVersion" item on the JSON config.